# Django - how to implement lock data

Tags: python, django

I have a database table. Some database items can be edited by a user, but only one user can edit the table content at a time, and if after 2 hours the user hasn't finished editing, other users can edit the table. How can I do this?

The table is like this:

```
class NodeRevision(BaseModel, NodeContent):
    node       = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='revisions')
    summary    = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    revision   = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    revised_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    suggested  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    suggest_status = models.CharField(max_length=16,default="")
```

Should I add a BooleanField to it, such as `editing_locked=models.BooleanField(default=False)` ? Or something else? And how could I implement the 2 hour check?

Answer (score 3):

You'd need a `locked_at` time field and `locked_by` field.

Every time somebody loads an edit page, update the database with the `locked_at` and `locked_by` information.

To implement the 2 hour restriction, I'd just have the results calculated only when a user asks for permission (as opposed to polling / updating models). When a user tries to edit a model, have it check `locked_by/locked_at` and return a Boolean whether it's editable by the user or not.

```
def can_edit(self, user):
    if user == self.locked_by:
         return True
    elif self.locked_at and (self.locked_at - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds > 2*60*60:
         return True
    return False
```

Comment: thanks  , i will have a try . i want to implement the suggest improve function like stackoverflow. you know , if you are improve a suggest , some one can accept it when you are doing improve editing , so , i don't know stackoverflow how implement it .